# What is best way to salt password?

Tags: passwords, salt

can you please tell me what is best way to salt password. Which method best?

Thank you.

Comment: It may be a bit of a 'dumb' comment, but: The method that comes with your framework.

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, of course - given that such a method *does* come with the framework. He hasn't specified anything about a framework, so we can't assume there even is a framework in the first place.

Comment: Which is why it's a 'dumb' comment, yes. :)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter how you do it.  It's just a way to get different hashes for the same password.

If you think you need 256 hashes for every password, use one byte of salt.
If you want 4bn hashes for every password, use 4 bytes of salt.

These kind of trade-offs need much more information about the problem domain than you've given us.

Assume that the salt is publicly visible, so you don't need to worry about fancy un-guessable techniques for predicting it - any old PRNG will do.

Answer (score 1):

A salt is just applying some mutation to your raw password before applying a hash (or encryption I guess) so that a rainbow table attack is more difficult. It can be as simple as:

```
md5("saltstring" + password);
```

Comment: Is `PsAaSlStWsOtRrD` superior to `saltstrPASSWORD`, or are they practically the same and not worth to try to shuffle the two strings?

Comment: It's a good question, and I'm not a security expert. I think there's little different (after all they'll both look like random strings once hashed). There's a few questions about on "salting best practices" that are probably better to review.